# Typescript async function without Promise type

Tags: javascript, typescript

When you will look at typescript async function you can clearly see redundancy with `async` and `Promise<type>`.

```
public async test(): Promise<string> {
  return "Test";
}
```

Is there way to configure typescrypt, to handle async types without `Promise<T>` type? Just `T` like:

```
public async test(): string {
  return "Test";
}
```

Im getting this when im trying to skip `Promise< >`: `The return type of an async function or method must be the global Promise<T> type. Did you mean to write 'Promise<number>'?ts(1064)`

`Question is about how to avoid writing boilerplate. We know that async fn() will always return a Promise, so why do I have to write Promise<T>` - @josh3736

Comment: That makes no sense - async functions ***always*** produce a promise. That's the entire point of them - to handle asynchronous operations. And the way you do this in JS is via promises. There is no way to convert an async function to synchronous, so you cannot return a plain value from it.

Comment: Yes, I know. But `async` means that function return type is Promise. So why need to write it twice?

Comment: @VLAZ: right, but I read this question as asking how to avoid writing boilerplate.  We know that `async fn()` will always return a `Promise`, so why do I have to write `Promise<T>`?

Comment: @josh3736 you don't HAVE to. In the example in OP [it's going to be correctly inferred](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsI2QUxMgCgEoYBvAWACgYYAnHZBWrAIgBU9kWBuKgXypVc+YlRo0AdMgAWOCAQAeMALwA+GAqnoAqgAddOWgGFQOYiQD0FgO7paAaxBjxU2fKiYQ6ADY4J39ABzIiA). So, if it's an issue with writing more code than necessary, it's not really a problem with TS - the inference will save you the typing in most occasions. Besides, you don't have "async" in ambient contexts, so the only valid signature for an async function is a function that produces a promise.

Comment: I suppose to avoid confusion. Its clearer and more explicit, prevents mistakes. Imagine hovering over a function and seeing that it returns a promise and then going to definition and seeing a string there.

Comment: You don't have to put `Promise<string>`, just leave it out and it will return a `Promise<string>` automatically, no extra boiler code required.

Comment: @Keith I added error that typescript linter(?) gives me. I would like to remove it

Comment: "*Im getting this when im trying to skip Promise< >*" - you can already skip it. If you don't provide a return type for the function or method TS will infer it from what you're returning. If you're wrote correct TS code, the compiler should know what you're returning and thus correctly assign the return type of the function/method. If you *have to* provide a return type, it suggests there is something wrong with your typings if TS cannot use them to deduce what your code does. Yes, in *some* cases you'd have to add the annotation explicitly but it shouldn't be often enough to be a bolerplate.

Comment: Did you put string?, dont... just leave out the string part too.   Also `'Promise<number>'`, it might an idea to show the code your getting this, and that's obviously not the same.

Comment: @Keith yes, function looked like in my question. I don't see reason why async is dangerous, and leaving function without type is not...

Comment: @Sahee reason 1.  you make the documentation of functions inconsistent. For *some* the return type is whatever the return type is. For *others* the return type isn't the true return type and [you have to read back and forth just to understand what the return type is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yo-yo_problem). 2. You are no longer able to accurately describe types like `Promise<string> | number` vs `Promise<string | number>`. Just off the top of my head. Also, I fail to understand why it's a problem: you claim it's boilerplate but you're imposing it on yourself by specifying a return type.

Comment: @VLAZ 1. So you don't yoyo if you see `public async x(){ return this.abc}`? Its same thing. 2. You can accurately describe types like `Promise<string> | number` just by `Promise<string> | number`. But you don't need to write `Promise< >` in every async function. Is there way to disable that `ts(1064)` error?

Comment: @Sahee *I've repeatedly told you* how to fix this - omit the return type. Why is this not an option? You're literally adding unnecessary code and then complaining it's unnecessary.

Comment: Thats not valid answer for me. I would like to leave type without `Promise<>`.  And leaving function without type is just bad. I will stick to that boilerplate

Comment: @VLAZ: I disagree that omitting the return type annotation is a "fix" or that having one is unnecessary.  By having an explicit return type, you protect not only the consumer of your method (which yes, you can also do by letting TS infer the type), but you also guard against implementation bugs in the method itself: ie `function foo(): string { return 1; }` is a compile-time error.  Had you omitted the return type, it would have happily compiled.  An explicit return type annotation is *not* boilerplate.

Comment: @josh3736 then why go halfway at all? The proper way to ensure the implementation is correct is to create explicit declarations separate from the implementation. Explicit declarations exists in the ambient context. There is no `async` in the ambient context. Ergo, there is no need to add `async` *and* `Promise`. Having explicitly typed function definitions is a patchwork fix that doesn't completely address the problem of type safety well and doesn't help out with less code, either. Not to mention, introducing complexity and other potential bugs. It's like wanting to use TS but not commit to it

Answer (score 0):

There was already such suggestion in TypeScript repository: [suggestion](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7284)
I agree with commenters that such "feature" could be confusing and dangerous.

Comment: I can't find reason why async with string type is dangerous, and async without type is not...

Comment: "There's also the fundamental tenet that a return type annotation shouldn't depend on modifiers on the other side of the screen to be interpreted correctly." One reason quoted from that thread.